# Elasticsearch().ping() displays errors from urllib3 if the server is not up

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have this expectation of `Elasticsearch.ping`: it should return `True` if Elasticsearch can be contacted, and `False` if it cannot. However, if connection cannot be established, `ping` will display a bunch of errors before finally returning `False`. Is there a way to prevent it? I really don't need all that, I just want my `False`.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import elasticsearch
>>> elasticsearch.Elasticsearch().ping()
HEAD http://localhost:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x109d19550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
HEAD http://localhost:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x109d195c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
HEAD http://localhost:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x109d196a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
HEAD http://localhost:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.002s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/amadan/work/aistqa/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x109d19780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an error that some people encountered : 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/666

to sum up the above discussion try and suppress the logger in elastic search to only log errors , like so:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

and see if it helps you .

EDIT: the OP fixed the problem i a more concrete way to `elasticsearch` with :

```
import logging; 
logging.getLogger('elasticsearch').level = logging.ERROR
```

both ways works.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I did a bit more targetted assassination: `import logging; logging.getLogger('elasticsearch').level = logging.ERROR`.

Comment: You are welcome , and yes - your way is far more concrete to the `elasticsearch` module, seems like a better way - will add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

For me the provided solution didn't work, since the starktrace is generated by `urllib3`. So for me this worked out:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```